# Failled to install Pillow using Pycharm

Tags: python, django, web, pycharm, python-imaging-library

**I am using Pycharm on windows 7 32bit, i am learning to make a website using django. i am trying to make imagefield, so i tried to install Pillow in the command window and it give me this error:**

```
(venv) C:\Users\مرحبا\PycharmProjects\TryDjango>py -m pip install Pillow
Collecting Pillow
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\مرحبا\AppData\Local\Programs\lib\site- 
packages\pip\_internal\basecommand.py", line 228, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "C:\Users\مرحبا\AppData\Local\Programs\lib\site- 
packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 291, in run
resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
File "C:\Users\مرحبا\AppData\Local\Programs\lib\site- 
packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 103, in resolve
self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
File "C:\Users\مرحبا\AppData\Local\Programs\lib\site- 
packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 257, in _resolve_one
abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
File "C:\Users\مرحبا\AppData\Local\Programs\lib\site- 
packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 210, in _get_abstract_dist_for
self.require_hashes
File "C:\Users\مرحبا\AppData\Local\Programs\lib\site- 
packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 245, in 
prepare_linked_requirement
   req.populate_link(finder, upgrade_allowed, require_hashes)
File "C:\Users\مرحبا\AppData\Local\Programs\lib\site- 
packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 307, in populate_link
self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
File "C:\Users\مرحبا\AppData\Local\Programs\lib\site- 
packages\pip\_internal\index.py", line 484, in find_requirement
all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
File "C:\Users\مرحبا\AppData\Local\Programs\lib\site- 
packages\pip\_internal\index.py", line 442, in find_all_candidates
for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
File "C:\Users\مرحبا\AppData\Local\Programs\lib\site- 
packages\pip\_internal\index.py", line 587, in _get_pages
page = self._get_page(location)
File "C:\Users\مرحبا\AppData\Local\Programs\lib\site- 
packages\pip\_internal\index.py", line 705, in _get_page
return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
File "C:\Users\مرحبا\AppData\Local\Programs\lib\site- 
packages\pip\_internal\index.py", line 814, in get_page
"Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
File "C:\Users\مرحبا\AppData\Local\Programs\lib\site- 
packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 521, in get
return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\مرحبا\AppData\Local\Programs\lib\site- 
packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 397, in request
return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\مرحبا\AppData\Local\Programs\lib\site- 
packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 508, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\مرحبا\AppData\Local\Programs\lib\site- 
packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 658, in send
r.content
File "C:\Users\مرحبا\AppData\Local\Programs\lib\site- 
packages\pip\_vendor\requests\models.py", line 823, in content
self._content = bytes().join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or bytes()
File "C:\Users\مرحبا\AppData\Local\Programs\lib\site- 
packages\pip\_vendor\requests\models.py", line 745, in generate
for chunk in self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True):
File "C:\Users\مرحبا\AppData\Local\Programs\lib\site- 
packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 436, in stream
data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
File "C:\Users\مرحبا\AppData\Local\Programs\lib\site- 
packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 384, in read
 data = self._fp.read(amt)
File "C:\Users\مرحبا\AppData\Local\Programs\lib\site- 
packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.py", line 63, in read
self._close()
File "C:\Users\مرحبا\AppData\Local\Programs\lib\site- 
packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.py", line 50, in _close
self.__callback(self.__buf.getvalue())
File "C:\Users\مرحبا\AppData\Local\Programs\lib\site- 
packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\controller.py", line 296, in cache_response
self.serializer.dumps(request, response, body=body),
File "C:\Users\مرحبا\AppData\Local\Programs\lib\site- 
packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 298, in set
return super(SafeFileCache, self).set(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\مرحبا\AppData\Local\Programs\lib\site- 
packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\caches\file_cache.py", line 113, in set
with self.lock_class(name) as lock:
File "C:\Users\مرحبا\AppData\Local\Programs\lib\site- 
packages\pip\_vendor\lockfile\mkdirlockfile.py", line 19, in __init__
LockBase.__init__(self, path, threaded, timeout)
File "C:\Users\مرحبا\AppData\Local\Programs\lib\site- 
packages\pip\_vendor\lockfile\__init__.py", line 226, in __init__
self.tname = '-%x' % (ident & 0xffffffff)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'method' and 'int'
```

actually i am beginner, please tell me what to do, i am at the last step to finish my first website, and i need to install the pillow in order to make imagefield in my model.
could you help me Please?

Comment: The (pip3 install Pillow) result this: (No module named pip3)

Answer (score 1):

First try the following-

```
pip install Pillow
```

If the above doesn't work, try the following-

```
pip3 install Pillow
```

**Edit 1:**

If pip is showing error, do the following-

1) Check which version of python you are using. The latest version is 3.8. See if the following shows any error?

```
python3
```

If the above command shows error, that means you may need to install the latest version of python from its [website](https://www.python.org/).

2) Check the pip version-

```
pip -V
# pip 20.0.2 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

The above should install the lates pip version (20.0.2). Then try to install `Pillow` with `pip`.

Comment: the ( pip install Pillow) result of the error which in my question.             The (pip3 install Pillow) result this: (No module named pip3)

Comment: Hey @BhaaNwajaa, try to follow the 'Edit 1' steps. We can check the pip version, upgrade if needed. And also your current Python version as well.

Comment: i tried to do the last command(py -m pip install --upgrade pip)  and the result is the same error which in my question